# Pandas dataframe filtering after groupby with irregular time series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame with a time series indexed by a timestamp, like this:

```
timestamp              A       B    
2018-11-12 14:03:53  9.45     501.0
2018-11-12 14:03:58  73.8     108.0
2018-11-12 14:04:09  4.25     215.0
2018-11-12 14:04:19  62.39    551.0
2018-11-12 14:04:29  15.98    113.0
```

I'd like to do some aggregations based on bins of this data, for example:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='30Min')).apply(custom_agg)
```

However, the problem is that both this grouper or `serialize` create a continuous range of bins, but my data is constrained to certain hours in each day (say, after 14.00). This leaves me with a huge number of groups without data:

```
2018-11-13 00:00:00    NaN    NaN        0.0
2018-11-13 00:30:00    NaN    NaN        0.0
2018-11-13 01:00:00    NaN    NaN        0.0
2018-11-13 01:30:00    NaN    NaN        0.0
2018-11-13 02:00:00    NaN    NaN        0.0
2018-11-13 02:30:00    NaN    NaN        0.0
2018-11-13 03:00:00    NaN    NaN        0.0
```

I'd like to filter these out. Using `df.filter()` wouldn't be of much use since the problem is not with the original rows but with the groups.

I tried to use `apply`: `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='30Min')).apply(lambda x: x[x.index.min().hour >= 14])`, but I get a `KeyError: True`. (Side question, why doesn't this work?)

What is the best way to filter a DataFrame on a given set of conditions involving the grouping **after** a `groupby` was applied?

Comment: Why don't you simply drop the nan values, f.i. `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='30Min')).apply(custom_agg).dropna(how='all', subset=['your_nan_column1', 'your_nan_column2'])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `.dt.floor`:

```
df.groupby(df['timestamp'].dt.floor('30Min')).apply(custom_agg)
```